# How do I properly create during runtime and read the properties that are stored in the config file that saved during a previous session?

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

I use this code here to create a user-scoped setting during runtime:

```
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty userScopedProperty = 
        new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("New Setting");

userScopedProperty.DefaultValue = "This setting default value";
userScopedProperty.IsReadOnly = false;
userScopedProperty.PropertyType = typeof(string);
userScopedProperty.Provider = 
         Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];

userScopedProperty.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), 
          new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());

Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(userScopedProperty);
Properties.Settings.Default["New Setting"] = "value changed to this";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Which for some reason only sometimes works and will create the settings in the userSettings section in the user.config file. While executing in the same session this works:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["New Setting"]
```

But as soon as I close the application and the start it up again, that line of code will give me a `System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException`. I have tried adding `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload()` right before attempting to read the setting but that doesnt seem to work either.

The goal of this portion of the project is to be able to create user settings during runtime, close the program, and when you start the program again you can view those settings. You should also be able to change them at any point. I run the program in Visual Studio in debug mode, not sure if that information is needed.

So my questions are:
How do I properly create during runtime and read the properties that are stored in the user.config file that I saved in a previous session? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` are only available in the current session. When you restart your app, you will see that your `Default` settings are always those defined in the `Settings.settings`. You can find the dynamically added properties in the `user.config` file. To retrieve your properties, you may use the method [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869001/668342).

Answer (score 0):

I generally keep settings like that in an XML file in *IsolatedStorage*.  I create a `ProgramSettings` class that I annotate for XML serialization (using `XmlRootAttribute`, `XmlElementAttribute`, and sometimes `XmlArrayAttribute` and `XmlArrayItemAttribute`) and then I use this class to read and write that XML settings file:

```
public static class PersistedSettings<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public static T LoadSettings(string applicationName, ISettingsErrorReporter errorReporter)
    {
        var filename = GetFileName(applicationName);
        try
        {
            using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null))
            {
                if (!isoStore.FileExists(filename))
                {
                    return new T();
                }
                //otherwise
                using (var settingsStream = isoStore.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    var settings = (T)serializer.Deserialize(settingsStream);
                    settingsStream.Close();
                    return settings;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            errorReporter.WriteError($"IO Exception:{Environment.NewLine}{ioException.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorReporter.WriteError($"Exception ({ex.GetType().Name}):{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}");
        }
        //no matter what kind of exception, 
        return new T();
    }

    public static void SaveSettings(string applicationName, T settings, ISettingsErrorReporter errorReporter)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null))
            {
                using (var settingsStream = isoStore.CreateFile(GetFileName(applicationName)))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    serializer.Serialize(settingsStream, settings);
                    //let's be safe and use both suspenders and a belt (Flush, Close, Dispose)
                    settingsStream.Flush();
                    settingsStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            errorReporter.WriteError($"I/O Exception:{Environment.NewLine}{ioException.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorReporter.WriteError($"Exception ({ex.GetType().Name}):{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private static string GetFileName(string applicationName)
    {
        return applicationName + ".xml";
    }
}
```

I usually use this from simple WinForms apps.  I make my Form class implement this interface:

```
public interface ISettingsErrorReporter
{
    void WriteError(string message);
}
```

(usually by popping up a message box)

Then I call `LoadSettings` in the FormLoad event and `SaveSettings` in the form closing event.

It's not what you are asking, but it may satisfy your needs